# Let a node delete itself on Buttonclick

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I created this simple Group to test some internal windows in a scene, but the "closebutton" cant remove, even if i reference the parent. do i have to add the button logic directly in the view itself ?

```
public class CircleAnchor extends Group {
        private Region region;

        public CircleAnchor(Region parent){
            this.region = parent;

            Circle c = new Circle(20, Color.RED);
            Rectangle closeButton = new Rectangle(10,10, Color.BEIGE);
            closeButton.setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent ->{
                if(mouseEvent.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY){
                    region.getChildren().remove(this);
                }
            });

            makeDragable(closeButton);




            getChildren().addAll(c,closeButton);
    setCache(true);

}
```

Its my first question..hope my problem is understandable.

Comment: Why create a `region` field when you seemingly could use the `parent` property? Also you are clicking the **secondary** mouse button, not the primary one when you're testing this, aren't you?

Comment: yes the primary button is used for the drag test. And region is a subclass of parent as i can see. the code as presented above is not working. i can just access the getChildrenUnmodifiable() from the parent region.

Comment: okay i had to refrence my own class that extends region.. im dumb. solved